# How to display text through TextField input?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm facing an issue regarding displaying my saved data, so what I want is as I enter data into the TextField, it should save and get displayed so far the saving works:

[Value being saved into the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBK67.png)

The saving works as the data inputted into the TextField gets saved in the list but to display the results from the list onto the home screen is a challenge.

Once the user enters into the app, the create button will lead to another screen and the user can input the value into the TextField with the help of the TextEditingController (_notescontroller2) which is then saved into the list and should be displayed onto the homescreen in the form of a card.
Any help would be appreciated.

This is the entire project code:

data is the list which stores all the values inputted.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

TextEditingController _notesController1 = new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _notesController2 = new TextEditingController();
List<String> data = [];

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    ));

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Glass',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  letterSpacing: 1.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Trash'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Glass',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            letterSpacing: 1.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
      ),
//The card which will display the results from the list.
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          child: ListTile(
            onTap:() {},
            title: Text(
              //Text to be displayed here.
            ),
          ),
          );
       },
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              elevation: 9.0,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async {
          await Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SharedPreference1()));
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[300],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    ));
  }
}

Future<bool> saveData(String nameKey, String value) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await preferences.setString(nameKey, value);
  }
Future<String> loadData(String nameKey) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getString(nameKey);
  }

class Hero extends State<SharedPreference1> {
  Widget buildSaveButton(context) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:340.0),
    child: RaisedButton.icon(
      elevation: 9.0,
      icon: Icon(Icons.save),
      label: Text('Save'),
      color: Colors.white,
      onPressed: () async {
        await saveData("_key_name", _notesController2.text);
        await setData();
        print(data);
              },
            ),
          ); 
        }      
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
        child: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                buildHeading(context),
                buildNotesText(),
                buildSaveButton(context),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setData();

  }
//Add the value onto the list.
  setData() {
    loadData("_key_name").then((value) {
      setState(() {
        if(value==null){
          print("Value not available.");
        }
        else{
          data.add(value);
        }

      });
    });
  }

}

Widget buildHeading(context) {
  return Material(
    color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 10.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              maxLines: 1,
              controller: _notesController1,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Note Title',
              ),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Montserrat',),
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white, size: 27),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget buildNotesText() {
  return Material(
    color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: TextField(
        maxLines: null,
        controller: _notesController2,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: 'Create Note Here',
        ),
        cursorColor: Colors.white,
        autofocus: true,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 18,fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class SharedPreference1 extends StatefulWidget {
  SharedPreference1() : super(); 
  @override
  Hero createState() => Hero();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your data-List at the position of the index to the Text-Widget.

```
body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: data.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Card(
        child: ListTile(
          onTap: () {},
          title: Text(data[index]),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

But after returning to Home the ListView doesn't rebuild automatically. After Hot reload the updated List is shown.

Comment: Okay so I had tried using data[0] in place of data[index], the way I was doing it wasn't correct. I understand now. It works now but with the hot reload in place, but what if I am using it on my actual device will it rebuild automatically?

Comment: I don't think so. Put your ListView in a StatefulWidget. StatelessWidgets are not mutable, but you want your ListView to updated automatically after pushing the save button.

Comment: Yes exactly, I'll give it a shot. Thanks for your help.